# Use interop and c# to count the rows in an Excel spreadsheet's worksheet with data in

Tags: c#, excel, com-interop

I have just written what has to be considered utterly hideous code to count the rows that contain data in the worksheets called "Data" from all the spreadsheets in a given directory. Here's the code

```
    private const string _ExcelLogDirectoryPath = @"..\..\..\..\Model\ExcelLogs\";
    static void Main()
    {
        var excelLogPaths = Directory.GetFiles(_ExcelLogDirectoryPath, "*.xl*");
        var excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        var excelRowCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (var filePath in excelLogPaths)
        {
            var spreadsheet = excel.Workbooks.Open(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath) + "/" + filePath);
            var worksheet = spreadsheet.Sheets["Data"] as Worksheet;
            if (worksheet != null)
            {
                // var rowCount = UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1; DOES NOT WORK, THE number is bigger than the 'real' answer
                var rowCount = 0;
                for (var i = 1 ; i < 1000000000; i++)
                {
                    var cell = worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value2; // "Value2", great name for a property, thanks guys
                    if (cell != null && cell.ToString() != "") // Very fragile (e.g. skipped rows will break this)
                    {
                        rowCount++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                var name = spreadsheet.Name.Substring(spreadsheet.Name.IndexOf('p'), spreadsheet.Name.IndexOf('.') - spreadsheet.Name.IndexOf('p'));
                excelRowCounts.Add(name, rowCount - 1);
            }
        }
```

I cannot believe this is the right way to do this. It is crazy slow and includes calls to properties with names like `Value2` that do not feel like an intended part of a public API. But the method [suggested elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/356478/575530) dramatically over reports the number of rows (with data in them).

What is the correct was to count the rows with data in them from an Excel worksheet?

========== EDIT 1 ==========

The reason that both `UsedRange.Rows.Count` and [Sid's ACE.OLEDB solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13534642/575530) over report the number of rows appears to be a pink background colour that is applied to some of the columns (but only extending to row 7091). Is there a simple/elegant way to count the rows with data in them (i.e. with non-null cell values) regardless of the display colour?

========== EDIT 2 ===========

[Sid's ACE.OLEDB solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13534642/575530) with [the addition he suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534241/use-interop-and-c-sharp-to-count-the-rows-in-an-excel-spreadsheets-worksheet-wi/13534642#comment18592298_13534642) so that the tSQL line reads

```
var sql = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM [" + sheetName + "$] WHERE NOT F1 IS NULL";
```

works. I'll mark that as the answer.

Comment: Is OleDb an option for you? If you only want to count used rows and don't care about formatting, it's a lot faster than Interop.

Comment: Is finding number of used rows, the most important code piece you need? If so, you may use high performance excel function and plug that into c# using interop. some [useful article](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/ExcelSpreadsheetDesign.htm)

Comment: Thanks Sid - do you have a pointer to how to use OleDb to count used rows in an Excel worksheet? Faster would be good!

Comment: Thanks bon - that article is about VBA and part of my problem (I think) is working out the translation between VBA in Excel and C# Interop from outside. For example the article recommends `Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row` but I don't know how to put that in C# Interop

Comment: This is quite old, but I believe it would be `Worksheet.Cells.Find("*", After: Worksheet.GetRange(1, 1), SearchOrder:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, SearchDirection: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious).Row;` 
and 
`this.worksheet.Cells.Find("*", After: this.worksheet.GetRange(1, 1), SearchOrder: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, SearchDirection: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious).Column` for last used column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick. You can call it with each filename to retrieve the number of rows.

```
private string GetNumberOfRows(string filename, string sheetName)
{
    string connectionString;
    string count = "";

    if (filename.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
    {
        connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO\"";
    }
    else if (filename.EndsWith(".xls"))
    {
        connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;\"";
    }

    string SQL = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM [" + sheetName + "$]";

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SQL, conn))
        {
            using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                reader.Read();
                count = reader[0].ToString();
            }
        }

        conn.Close();
    }

    return count;
}
```

There might be an even faster way of retrieving just the row count, but I know this works.

Comment: If it's an xlsm file do I treat it the same as xlsx?

Comment: Hmmm...not sure. I would treat it according to the version of Excel in which it was created. For 2003 and earlier treat it like a .xls and for 2007 and later treat it like a .xlsx. I've not tried macro-enabled workbooks so you might need to give it a test.

Comment: I'm got an `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine` error. I'm on Win 8 using Office 2013 and followed the instructions in [Accessing Excel files on a x64 machine](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/farukcelik/archive/2010/06/04/accessing-excel-files-on-a-x64-machine.aspx) to download from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en&WT.mc_id=soc-n-[TR]-loc-[Services]-[farukc])

Comment: Sadly this code does not seem to work. For example one of the Excel spreadsheets has 312 rows with data in but this code reports 7090 rows. Indeed it over-reports the number of data rows as 7090 for most of the 19 spreadsheets, just as `UsedRange.Rows.Count` did too

Comment: @dumbledad Interesting. Are you sure there isn't anything else about those cells that might cause then to appear as being used? It would seem odd that everything you've tried over-counts to exactly the same number.

Comment: I'll try that on Monday and let you know. Perhaps if I scan along row 7090 (by eye or programmatically) I'll find some rogue data.

Comment: I think I've got it. Some of the columns in the spreadsheet have a pink background colour. Your code Sid seems to include the pink cells as part of the content (just as UsedRange does). Is it straightforward to change your tSQL to only include cells with non-null values (regardless of their background colour)?

Comment: @dumbledad Interesting, I didn't realise that OleDb included rows without text. At first glance there is a way around it: in the SQL you can include a condition with excludes nulls, but you'll need to do it for every column: `SELECT COUNT (*) FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE NOT (F1 IS NULL AND F2 IS NULL AND F3 IS NULL ...)` if you don't have headers, or name the headers if you do.

Comment: What are the F1, F2, etc in this Sid?

Comment: @dumbledad They are what's used to reference each column if you don't have column headers and your connection string contains `HDR=NO`. If you have `HDR=YES` and you know the names of the headers then you can use those instead. It's a bit of a roundabout way of rejecting empty rows, but it's all I can think of at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

if you use interop is why don't use UsedRange?

```
_Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Comment: I mention that in my question (and it is a row commented out in the code I list). I found that `UsedRange.Rows.Count` over reported the number of rows with data in. Not sure why, perhaps old formatting? Though that should be refreshed by the call (I think)